# FormatException: Unexpected character in JSON

Tags: flutter

I have an app which takes a `Widget` and converts its to a `String` and then to a `Json`.

I get the Exception: `FormatException: Unexpected character(at character 20)`.
I want that the Widget can you converted to a `Json`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static String _widget = Text('D').toString();
  static String rawJson = """{"widget":"L($_widget..replaceAll(" ", ' '))L"}""";
  static Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
  static String widgete = map['widget'];
  WidgetJson widgetJson = WidgetJson(widget: widgete);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_widget);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Widget Title"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[Text("$widgete")],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetJson {
  WidgetJson({this.widget});
  String widget;
}
```

Comment: A slight tangent: why?

Comment: I want to make an App which needs to convert a Widget to a JSON

Answer (score 0):

Declare a map using map literals

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = { 'widget' : Text('D').toString()};
```

`map['widget']` will produce the following output

> Text("D")

Comment: how can i convert to json?